# R read_excel reads numeric data incorrectly

Tags: r, excel, tidyverse

I'm trying to download and parse the Data worksheet in the file ie_data.xls from Professor Robert Shiller's home page ([http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eshiller/data.htm)). I download the file from [http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data/ie_data.xls](http://www.econ.yale.edu/%7Eshiller/data/ie_data.xls), and then run the following script:

```
library(tidyverse)
ie_data <- read_excel("ie_data.xls", sheet = "Data", col_names = TRUE, 
                       col_types = "numeric", na = "", skip = 7) %>% 
           select(Date,E) %>%
           drop_na()
```

A bunch of warnings are generated, but more bothersome is the output

```
> names(ie_data)
[1] "Date" "E"   
> ie_data
# A tibble: 1,791 x 2
    Date     E
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1871.   0.4
 2 1871.   0.4
 3 1871.   0.4
 4 1871.   0.4
 5 1871.   0.4
 6 1871.   0.4
 7 1871.   0.4
 8 1871.   0.4
 9 1871.   0.4
10 1871.   0.4
# ... with 1,781 more rows
Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

The contents of both columns should have two decimal places (1871.01 represents January 1871, 1871.02 represents February 1871 and so on, and the second column is earnings per share rounded to the nearest penny), but everything after the decimal point is gone in the first column at the head of the dataframe! Even more mysterious is its tail:

```
> tail(ie_data)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
   Date     E
  <dbl> <dbl>
1 2019.  135.
2 2019.  137.
3 2019.  139.
4 2020.  132.
5 2020.  124.
6 2020.  116.
Warning message:
`...` is not empty.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `needs_dots`

These dots only exist to allow future extensions and should be empty.
Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Now both columns have lost their fractional part! What change do I need to make to my code in order to read these columns correctly?

Sincerely and with many thanks in advance

Thomas Philips

Comment: I used the same code that you have listed above, and if you type `print(ie_data$Date)` you will see that the decimal places exist in your data. You can also click on `ie_data` in your Global Env or `View(ie_data)` in the console, and you will see that the decimal places are present.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to see more significant digits in your console when printing your data with `ie_data`. This doesn't affect your data, only the way it is shown when printed to your console.

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 10)
ie_data
```

Which will show:

```
  Date     E
     <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1871.01   0.4
 2 1871.02   0.4
 3 1871.03   0.4
 4 1871.04   0.4
 5 1871.05   0.4
 6 1871.06   0.4
 7 1871.07   0.4
 8 1871.08   0.4
 9 1871.09   0.4
10 1871.1    0.4
# ... with 1,781 more rows
```

If you use the following:

```
options(pillar.sigfig = 1)
ie_data
```

You will get:

```
# A tibble: 1,791 x 2
    Date     E
   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 1871.   0.4
 2 1871.   0.4
 3 1871.   0.4
 4 1871.   0.4
 5 1871.   0.4
 6 1871.   0.4
 7 1871.   0.4
 8 1871.   0.4
 9 1871.   0.4
10 1871.   0.4
# ... with 1,781 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you everyone - this is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

try it with `col_types = "text"`
Don't really know why numeric will get you trimmed numbers but i seem to get it working with text (provided you later convert to a rounded number)